# Append to array[i] (first element) until compare condition is no longer True

Tags: python, arrays

I have two arrays initialized like so:

```
bins = [['1'], ['2'],...['10']]

tasks = ['1:x', '1:y', '2:x', '2:y', '2:z'.... '10:x', '10:y']
```

I was trying to iterate through `[tasks]` and compare the string value before ':' to each element in `[bins]`, and if it matches append `tasks[i]` to `bins[i]`. So I am expecting `bins` to be updated like so:

```
bins = [[1, 1:x, 1:y]...[10, 10:x, 10:y]]
```

Then I thought it made sense to split off the content before the ':' in [tasks] to compare effectively, so
I split off the contents of `[tasks]` before the ':' and created a new array:

```
splits = ['1', '1', '2', '2', .....'10', '10']
```

Now in my code I am actually iterating through `[splits]` and trying to append `tasks[i]` if `splits[i]` is in `bins[i]`, using the code below:

```
for i in range(len(splits)):
    if (splits[i] in bins[i]) == True:
        bins[i].extend(tasks[i])
```

The problem is the code above does not find any matches (never returns a `True`), and thus `bins[i]` is not updated.

Am I not iterating through my arrays correctly? Am I not comparing correctly? How can I compare the first element of `[bins]` to each element of `[splits]` until it does not match and move onto the next element of `bins[i]` and repeat?

Comment: `splits` contains strings; `bins` contains lists.  So there will never be a match.  Changing the elements of one to the format of the other (so, for example, `splits` would be `[[1], [1], [2], [2], .....[10], [10]]`) would simplify things a lot.

Comment: You don't have an [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html), you have a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list).

Comment: Use dictionaries to do lookup

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is happening because you are comparing different datatypes. `Bin`s contains lists of numbers and `split`s contains strings.

Looking at you're questions, it seems like you want something like this:

```
for a in enumerate(bins):
    for b in enumerate(splits):
        if bins[a][0] == splits[b]
            bins[a].extend(tasks[b])
```

- Calling enumerate is the same as calling range(len(bins))
- Since the ellements in bins are ints, in lists you want the element on index `i` and the first (and only element) in the list (if `i` was 0 that would be bins[0] which is [1] and then [1][0] and 1 is the element on index 0)

Comment: I just edited my initial question - made a mistake when typing out bins, the elements in bins are actually also strings so I am comparing two lists. I just double checked the type of both bins[i] and tasks[i] and they are both lists. so I am comparing two lists. 

Now I am wondering if  "if bins[i] in splits[i]" will work if comparing two lists?

Comment: I updated my code example, bins[i] and tasks[i] are the same datatype(lists) but we are comparing bins[i] and splits[i](a list and a string), that's why i put bins[i][0] there instead

Comment: Okay, implementing your example

for i in enumerate(bins):
    for j in enumerate(splits):
        if bins[i][0] == splits[j]:
            bins[i].extend(tasks[j])
 I get this error:
" if bins[i][0] == splits[j]:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple"

BUT if I use 
"for i in range(len(bins)...."
 I get an "list index out of range" error pointing at the same line as tuple error.

both lists are the same length/type however so I'm confused about both errors

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing string against int

```py
>>> '1' in [1]
False
>>> '1' in [str(1)]
True
>>> int('1') in [1]
True
```

So do the:

```
int(splits[i])
```

And it should send true.

Upd. Regarding your correction, though your code should be working, try to make it more pythonic, maybe that will do better.

```
>>> if ('1' in ['1']) == True:
...     True
... 
True
>>> if ('1' in ['1']) == False:
...     True

... 
>>> if '1' in ['1']:
...    print("do things")
... do things

if splits[i] in bins[i]:
   bins[i].extend(tasks[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to work for me:

```
for i in range(len(tasks)):
  for j in range(len(bins)):
    if int(tasks[i][0]) in bins[j]:
      bins[j].append(tasks[i])
print(bins)
```